# ECDSA private key format

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, file-format

Here's a sample ECDSA private key (I don't use it for anything):

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIFL3sLnioGcDvHWM/BPlNw96BOx1KKco2qsq4UwhQUosoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAEXs1Fmq4QdPAbn3NycdEU+HOjc3kW9efbso2kI/vdDTWcSCMk310s53G3
tRClDBPPuuJAsKghbPfaTaUpmXFCNA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Here's what OpenSSL's asn1parse says about it:

```
    0:d=0  hl=2 l= 116 cons: SEQUENCE
    2:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim:  INTEGER           :01
    5:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim:  OCTET STRING
   39:d=1  hl=2 l=   7 cons:  cont [ 0 ]
   41:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim:   OBJECT            :1.3.132.0.10
   48:d=1  hl=2 l=  68 cons:  cont [ 1 ]
   50:d=2  hl=2 l=  66 prim:   BIT STRING
```

My question: where is this format defined?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find the definition in [RFC 5915](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5915).

It defines an `ECPrivateKey` object:

```
ECPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
 version        INTEGER { ecPrivkeyVer1(1) } (ecPrivkeyVer1),
 privateKey     OCTET STRING,
 parameters [0] ECParameters {{ NamedCurve }} OPTIONAL,
 publicKey  [1] BIT STRING OPTIONAL
}
```

From Section 3:

> The fields of type `ECPrivateKey` have the following meanings:

> - `version` specifies the syntax version number of the elliptic curve
>   private key structure.  For this version of the document, it SHALL
>   be set to `ecPrivkeyVer1`, which is of type `INTEGER` and whose value
>   is one (1).

> - `privateKey` is the private key.  It is an octet string of length
>   ceiling $(\log_2(n)/8)$ (where $n$ is the order of the curve) obtained
>   from the unsigned integer via the Integer-to-Octet-String-
>   Primitive (I2OSP) defined in [RFC3447](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447).

> - `parameters` specifies the elliptic curve domain parameters
>   associated to the private key.  The type `ECParameters` is discussed
>   in [RFC5480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480).  As specified in [RFC5480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480), only the `namedCurve`
>   CHOICE is permitted.  `namedCurve` is an object identifier that
>   fully identifies the required values for a particular set of
>   elliptic curve domain parameters.  Though the ASN.1 indicates that
>   the parameters field is OPTIONAL, implementations that conform to
>   this document MUST always include the parameters field.

> - `publicKey` contains the elliptic curve public key associated with
>   the private key in question.  The format of the public key is
>   specified in Section 2.2 of [RFC5480](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5480).  Though the ASN.1 indicates
>   `publicKey` is OPTIONAL, implementations that conform to this
>   document SHOULD always include the publicKey field.  The `publicKey`
>   field can be omitted when the public key has been distributed via
>   another mechanism, which is beyond the scope of this document.
>   Given the private key and the parameters, the public key can
>   always be recomputed; this field exists as a convenience to the
>   consumer.

---

As pointed out in the comments, OpenSSL actually uses a slightly different format, namely the SEC1 format found in SECG's [SEC 1: Elliptic Curve Cryptography](http://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf). From the description of [the `openssl ec` command](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ec.html):

> -inform DER|PEM

> - This specifies the input format. The DER option with a private key uses an ASN.1 DER encoded SEC1 private key.

However, as was also noted, the differences are small even if they are worth noting. From RFC 5915's Appendix B:

> This appendix lists the differences between this document and
> SECG1:

> 1. This document uses the I2OSP routine defined in RFC3447 while
>    SECG1 defines its own routine.  The two routines result in the
>    same output.

> 2. SECG1 constrains its parameters (i.e., the curves) to
>    SECGCurveNames.  This document constrains the parameters to
>    NamedCurve from RFC5480.

> 3. This document requires parameters be present while SECG1 does
>    not.

> 4. This document specifies requirements for encoding rules while
>    SECG1 did not.

Comment: Given OpenSSL implemented this long before 2010, I'm pretty sure they actually followed SECG 'SEC1', which is effectively identical -- especially since OpenSSL _does_ implement non-named 'explicit' parameters (Fp and F2m) and at least used to _default_ to them on the API, frequently causing interop trouble.

Comment: Wow, thanks. Edited the post to add this discussion.

Comment: what format is this: 
0 43 25 c4
d7 9 f1 9a
46 f7 4a 7c
9e de c2 b3
22 90 47 d1
15 c f4 f0
b 86 5 cc
0 0 0 0
45 e dc df
e9 37 34 2
ad 53 b4 95
66 a1 a b4
3c 44 44 37
c3 93 c8 85
18 c9 b3 58
15 8e 79 6a

Comment: What I understood from above that all private keys should start with 01 however example in question starts with 0x30... If we convert base64 to binary. Can someone please explain? thanks

Comment: 0x30 is a DER byte, not a private key byte. Use an ASN1 parser (such as lapo.it/asn1js) to peek into the DER.